# noncopyable, but movable container

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers, language-lawyer

I have a problem with this program:

```
struct A {};

int main()
{
  ::std::vector< ::std::unique_ptr<A> > v;

  ::std::cout << ::std::is_copy_constructible<decltype(v)>{} << ::std::endl;

  //decltype(v) w(v);

  return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
1
```

Yet, if I uncomment the commented line, the program will fail to compile. Do you think, it is a bug in the standard, that `::std::is_copy_constructible<decltype(v)>{}` evaluates to `true` and where in the standard? Should, for example, the metafunction be fixed, or should the container delete it's copy constructor, if the `value_type` is not copyable?

EDIT: I suppose I should clarify why this is important. Say, you have a class template `variant`, that contains a container class template instantiated with a non-copyable `value_type`. The `variant` could `SFINAE` away methods that copy the container and avoid compile errors, but since it receives wrong information from the `STL`, it can't. As a result of this problem, I've had to write a special `moving_variant` class template, that only moves, never copies, whereas it could/should be possible to have a single `variant` class template.

Comment: Be careful with your formatting: `<:` is interpreted as `[`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour not since C++11 if the sequence is `<::`. This is specified in 2.5/3 [lex.pptoken].

Comment: @Simple: OK, I guess my compiler hasn't caught up with that change.

Comment: +1, interesting. I'd say it's a bug, but not in the Standard, rather in the implementation.

Comment: @AndyProwl But then, the Standard would need to require such behavior from containers. I don't remember seeing it there.

Comment: @user1095108: Not sure I understand what you mean. To me, Table 49 is pretty clear about what `is_copy_constructible` should return. It is meant to resolve to `is_constructible<T, T const&>`, and 20.10.4.3/6 specifies that in order for that to be true, the expression `T t(create<T const&>())` must be well-formed, which is not the case for a vector of unique pointers (using draft N3797).

Comment: @AndyProwl: But surely the expression itself is well-formed? It will only fail if it's used in an evaluated context, since that will try to instantiate the copy constructor, which will try to call a deleted function.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I'm not sure I understand what "well-formed" means then. I thought "well-formed" is something that does not require the compiler to emit a diagnostic. But `T t(create<const T&>())` should lead to a diagnostic if `T` is not copy-constructible, and so it is not well-formed. Is my logic flawed?

Comment: @AndyProwl: I don't know. I really should steer clear of language-lawyer questions, as I soon lose track of the various shades of validness.

Comment: What is the normative meaning of the statement in 20.10.4.3/6: "Only the validity of the immediate context of the variable initialization is considered."?

Comment: Given the note following, "The evaluation of the initialization can result in side effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations and function template specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, and so on. Such side effects are not in the “immediate context” and can result in the program being ill-formed.", one could interpret it to mean that `T` having a non-deleted copy constructor declaration makes this use well-formed, even though that constructor could never be instantiated.

Comment: Other occurrences of the phrase "immediate context" in N3797 include similar notes (7.1.6.4/12, 14.8.2/8, 20.10.6/4, Table 49 and Table 57) such as "[ Note: The compilation of
the expression can result in side
effects such as the instantiation of
class template specializations and
function template specializations, the
generation of implicitly-defined
functions, and so on. Such side effects
are not in the “immediate context”
and can result in the program being
ill-formed. —end note ]"

Answer (score 7):

`is_copy_constructible` is defined in terms of `is_constructible`, which is true if an expression like this is well-formed:

```
T t(create<const T&>())
```

In the case of `vector<unique_ptr>`, this is well-formed, since `vector` declares a suitable copy constructor. The constructor can't be instantiated since it uses a deleted function; but templates aren't instantiated when used in an unevaluated context like this.

Comment: So both the implementation and the Standard are correct?

Comment: @user1095108: As far as I can see, yes. But a higher-level language lawyer might come along and find a flaw in my logic.

Comment: My question does not only have to do with the legalese of the Standard, real-life bugs and crashes were caused because of this.

Comment: @user1095108: If the question is an opinion-based "should the standard be changed", then I don't have enough knowledge of the potential consequences of the change to have an objective opinion. Also, that would be off-topic.

Comment: All right, but could the copy constructor of `vector<unique_ptr>` not `SFINAE`d away? I think it could.

Comment: @user: It could, but the standard doesn't specify it to be. Also, even if the trait gives a false positive, the compiler should complain as soon as you actually try it. How does that lead to 'real-life bugs and crashes'?

Comment: @Xeo You have a valid point: I don't know. Just kept hacking until I got it right and got some crashes in the mean time. Maybe you could write your own opinion on whether the Standard is wrong on this or not.